# Maximum likelihood + Kernel Density Estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, kernel-smoothing

Here my problem. I have a limited data sets of random variables $x: x_1, x_2, ..., x_N$. I can estimate the probability density function of $x$ by mean of Kernel Density Estimation method. (It works quite well in comparing with the complete data sets).

But how can I determine the "true" mean value of $x$? Which hypotheses must be added?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't determine the population mean from a sample.

However, you can estimate it.

Unless you know (or can assume) a distribution, why would you not simply estimate the population mean by the sample mean?

Answer (score 1):

For a reasonably large set of observations, the [Weak Law of Large Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_law_of_large_numbers) ensures that the sample mean is a consistent estimator of the population mean. The requirements are quite mild, we only have to assume that the observations are iid from a population with finite mean *but not finite variance*.

Alternatively, again for reasonably large samples, a Confidence Interval can be formed by exploiting the Central Limit Theorem, namely that the random variable:

$$\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}\to^D N\left(0,1 \right)$$

Then you can "pivot" it and obtain the desired CI for a specified value of $\alpha$:

$$1-\alpha=P\left(\bar{X}-z_{\alpha/2}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}<\mu <\bar{X}+z_{\alpha/2} \frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}\right) $$

where $z_{\alpha/2}$ is the upper $\alpha/2$ critical point of a standard normal distribution, i.e. $P \left(Z>z_{\alpha/2}\right)=\alpha/2$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Finite variance is not needed for the LLN.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Don't you use Chebyshev's inequality to prove it? If the variance is infinite you cannot prove the probability goes to zero.

Comment: We use Chebyshev's inequality to prove Chenyshev's WLLN, which indeed requires finite variance, but also permits non-identical r.v.'s. When the r.v's are i.i.d. we can apply Khintchine's WLLN, which only requires bounded mean.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos This might be so in an advanced text but an intermediate one makes use of the conditions I outlined. See for example Hogg, Craig and McKean, "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics", 7th edition, page 290.

Comment: Alecos stated "Finite variance is not needed for the LLN" ... and that statement is true. What you linked to specifically discusses Khintchine's law. I think the condition in Alecos' comment is completely consistent with your reference to the WLLN and the link you gave. You should probably just weaken the condition you mention. If you want to then specifically discuss the [finite variance case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Proof_using_Chebyshev.27s_inequality), by all means do so.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes indeed, the wikipedia artcicle states that finite variance is not needed and since it was me who provided it I will weaken the assumption. There exist references that point to the contrary, however, like the second one I provided.

Comment: The layers of knowledge and refinement are always applicable of course, but accuracy never hurts. Under the "i.i.d" assumption the "finite variance" assumption is neither sufficient, nor necessary -and so, it is not a "requirement" as you write. It is just a convenient additional property postulated in order to prove the Law easily -which is fine for educational purposes of course -my comment objected to the, strictly speaking, propagation of the wrong impression that the finite variance is a prerequisite for the LLN under i.i.d. And the same comment applies to the textbook you mention.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I see, thank you for pointing it out, I have now fixed it.